# How to make a landline phone ring periodically

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, telephone

How can I use a capacitor to ring a landline phone over and over again. I assume I need to develop such a circuit like below with a cap placed on one of wires. I think the cap would charge, and when decharging, it can ring the landline phone. If such a scheme is possible, does anybody know how I can calculate the needed capacitance for the cap.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4bC82.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No, that won't work.  The ring voltage supplied by the central office is (if I recall correctly) pulses of about 90 Volt 20 Hz AC.  There is no simple way to reproduce that with a few passive components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a capacitor in series with a phone like that will allow it to ring when the "main distribution facitilty" (I'm assuming you mean FXS, central office, or PABX etc) signals a ring but it will not be able to answer or make calls.  it will not cause it to ring at other times .

For the capacitor 10uF 100V non-polarised sounds about right.

Some phones may behave strangely in this configuration at they require a DC supply for correct on-hook operation. (eg Alcatel TF200 series)

Now, if you have a phone and want to make it ring you need the 90V AC  mentioned in the comments, you can find this on a ringing phone line. or make it using a PABX  or FXS adaptor or a ring generator circuit.